# Kubernetes 1.19 is out! Get it in one command with sudo snap install microk8s

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have three Ubuntu VM on Microsoft Azure. Every-time I login (through ssh) on my VMs in the Azure I see the following hint:

```
* Kubernetes 1.19 is out! Get it in one command with:

 sudo snap install microk8s --channel=1.19 --classic
```

I know Kubernetes is for resource manager But I didn't install Kubernetes in my VMs. What does it mean when I login in my VMs on Azure?? How I must to do??

Comment: Is it MOTD perhaps? You can disable it on `/etc/default/motd-news`

Comment: @kortewegdevries That's right. Thank you.